# ValueError:too many values to unpack Csv File

Tags: python, csv

Given a list of strings I am trying to manipulate each string in the list.

The list is `data[0]`

```
import csv
data = []
with open('twomoon.csv','rb') as csvfile:
    fd  = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
    for row in fd:
        data.append(row)
listX, listY, flag = [], [], []

for z in data[0]:
    for xy in z.split(','):
        x, y = xy.strip('[] ').split(' ')
        listX.append(float(x))
        listY.append(float(y))
```

I get a `Too many values to unpack` error.

Comment: What do you get from `xy.strip('[] ').split(' ')`?

Comment: Do you have en empty line at the end of the file?

Comment: This is used to format the string data...I have it in the form [1.345 -3.678]..

Comment: no i dont have an empty line at the end of file .

Comment: I can easily print the normal list using print data[0] but i am unable to format each element of this list